# Does Orthogonal matrix have complex eigenvectors with the same absolute value? If it is true, how can I prove it?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Does Orthogonal matrix have complex eigenvectors with the same absolute value (or modulus or magnitude)?  If it is true, how can I prove it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Do you mean complex eigenvalues?

Comment: no, I mean complex eigenvectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $A$ has eigenvector $x$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $kx$ is also an eigenvector for any non-zero $k \in \Bbb C$.

So, every matrix, orthogonal or otherwise, has a set of eigenvectors of identical length.

Comment: This is not what I ask. Sorry for my unclear question. My question is if orthogonal matrix $A$ has two complex eigenvectors $v_1$ $v_2$ associated with complex eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ $\lambda_2$, then the absolute values $\|v_1\|$ = $\|v_2\|$ ?

Comment: @congliu the choices $v_1,v_2$ are never unique.  However, we can always choose $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $\|v_1\| = \|v_2\| = 1$, for example.

Comment: yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix, $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ a $\lambda$-eigenvector. Then $\|v\|^2=v\cdot v=(Av)\cdot (Av)=\|Av\|^2=|\lambda|^2\|v\|^2$ and hence $|\lambda|=1$.